# Python Azure Function Remote App publish error

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-core-tools

Whenever I am trying to publish Azure Function for Python app on Azure Function then I got the below error:-

I want to publish azure function for python using the command line
command:- `func azure functionapp <Function Name> --Python`

[image]

But whenever I am trying it on local using `func host start` then it works.

Is there any way to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Hi Akshay, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with the commands below:

```
func azure functionapp publish <your function app name> --build remote
```

or

```
func azure functionapp publish <your function app name> --build local
```

I usually use these two commands to deploy the python function from VS code to Azure. For more information about these commands, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#publishing-to-azure).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any python modules installed that are not referenced in the requirements.txt file? That could possibly result in a failed deployment. After pip installing the modules, you should add them to the requirements.txt file in the following format:

```
requests==2.19.1
```

You can then generate the requirements.txt file by execution the below cmdlet:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then as Hury Shen mentioned, you can deploy using either of the two commands. I have found that it deploys successfully when using the --build remote command.